# Heat maps with Gnuplot, why the program does not depict anything

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I have a real matrix into a prova3hm.txt file, where each row is separated by a blank line. For example:

```
0.907 0.796 0.796 0.794 0.794 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.791 0.791

0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.79 0.79 0.79 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789

0.789 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.784 0.658 0.658 0.658 0.657 0.657

0.657 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.654 0.654 0.654 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653

0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652

0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651

0.651 0.651 0.651 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.649 0.649

0.649 0.649 0.649 0.649 0.648 0.648 0.648 0.646 0.242 0.241 0.24 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.238 0.238 0.238 0.238 0.238

0.238 0.238 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236

0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235

0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235

0.234 0.234 0.234 0.234 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232

0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.231 0.231 0.231 0.231 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23

0.229 0.229 0.165 0.164 0.163 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159

0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158

0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157
```

I need to get a **heat map** out of this file, with Gnuplot.
I have been trying to use the `pm3d` package and the `splot` command, this way:

`gnuplot> set pm3d map`

`gnuplot> splot 'prova3hm.txt' matrix`

At this point, I was **supposing** to get my heat map, that is something like this:
[image: Heatmap example]
<sub>(source: [pnas.org](http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2006/11/29/0609333103.DC1/09333Fig3.jpg))</sub>

But, instead, I got an **empty** image:

[image]

**Why is my output image empty?
What do I do wrong?**

Comment: I've edited the question, can you remove the "off-topic" flag? Thanks

Comment: Just remove the blank lines and use `plot "file" matrix with image`.

Comment: I tried, same result...

Answer (score 0):

The following script works fine with gnuplot version 4.6.3:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
set autoscale fix
plot 'file.txt' matrix with image
```

The result is:

[image]

To complete is, here the test data:

```
0.907 0.796 0.796 0.794 0.794 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.793 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.792 0.791 0.791
0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.791 0.79 0.79 0.79 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789 0.789
0.789 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.788 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.787 0.784 0.658 0.658 0.658 0.657 0.657
0.657 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.656 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.655 0.654 0.654 0.654 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653
0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.653 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652
0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.652 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651 0.651
0.651 0.651 0.651 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.649 0.649
0.649 0.649 0.649 0.649 0.648 0.648 0.648 0.646 0.242 0.241 0.24 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.239 0.238 0.238 0.238 0.238 0.238
0.238 0.238 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.237 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236
0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.236 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235
0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235 0.235
0.234 0.234 0.234 0.234 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.233 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232
0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.232 0.231 0.231 0.231 0.231 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23 0.23
0.229 0.229 0.165 0.164 0.163 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159 0.159
0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158 0.158
0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157 0.157
```

Comment: Thanks, but still gets the same result... :-( I'm usin': G N U P L O T
 Version 4.4 patchlevel 3
 last modified March 2011
 System: Linux 3.5.0-47-generic

Comment: Did you try with the exact data file and script file I posted? For me it works even with 4.2.6 on Linux (in that case with `set terminal png`, but thats not the point).